# Grab a value from a string using Regex

Tags: regex

I have a link that I want to grab a specific character out of. This is the link in question

```
"https://example.com/example-myexample/from/MyHouse/to/48DFjjhf333333333/view"
```

I want to grab the following id 48DFjjhf333333333 from this link using a regular expression. In this link /to/ and /view never change. The only thing that ever changes is the id that you see 48DFjjhf333333333.

I've tried the following regular expression:

```
\/to(.*?)\/view
```

This grabs everything along with /to/ and /view as follows /to/48DFjjhf333333333/view. I want to grab just the ID itself 48DFjjhf333333333

Comment: You need to get the access to Group 1 value. What is your language?

Comment: I'm using javascript

Comment: If your regex engine allow you may could use positive look behind like `(?<=\/to\/)[^/]+`. See: https://regex101.com/r/p0RkEe/1

Answer (score -1):

You just need to access the matching group with [1]

```js
console.log("https://example.com/example-myexample/from/MyHouse/to/48DFjjhf333333333/view".match(/\/to\/(.*?)\/view/)[1])
```